# Static reference to non-static method Error

Tags: java

I cannot figure out what I have done wrong in the following code segment:

```
private Door openOtherDoor(Door prizeDoor, Door selectedDoor){
Door.setPrize(prizeDoor.doorPrize);
Door.open(selectedDoor.doorPrize);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method open(boolean) from the type Door
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The method `open` is not static, but you are calling it from a static method. Change the method to `public static void open(boolean b)`

Comment: Almost certainly not. You should call `this.open()` instead of `Door.open()`. If you make it static you won't know which `Door` to open. @TheCoffeeKid

Comment: Oh, didn't know that :P

Answer (score -1):

if those methods are in the class Door, then you can do

```
private Door openOtherDoor(Door prizeDoor, Door selectedDoor){
Door.setPrize(prizeDoor.doorPrize);
Door.open(selectedDoor.doorPrize);
```

if `setPrize` is an static method, otherwise you will need the instance method i.e

```
private Door openOtherDoor(Door prizeDoor, Door selectedDoor){
    this.setPrize(prizeDoor.doorPrize);
    this.open(selectedDoor.doorPrize);
```

Comment: setPrize is in the class Door that why I am confused

Comment: No, he can *not* do `Door.open(...).`. It's non-static. That's what the error message says, and it's what the question is about.

Answer (score -1):

According to error. You should define open method in Door class as static.

Comment: So how does it know which door to open?